# PDO class could not be found in PhpStorm

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpstorm, intellisense

So, here is some code that I have in my project. Recently started to use PDO methods for connecting to database etc. The problem is that the IDE that I am using (PhpStorm) can't for some reason find any `PDO` classes. PhpStorm just shows a yellow line underneath the word and says 'Undefined class PDO'.

The weird thing is that if I put a `\` before the word `PDO`, (ie. `\PDO`) then the class can now be found. I know that from doing some research that you can include it like so `use \PDO`, however I don't really want to have to do that.

[image: The issue that I am getting]

Lastly, wanted to mention that in external libs within PhpStorm that PDO is included which is even more confusing but hopefully you guys would be able to help me out with this.

[image: PDO files included within PhpStorm]

> EDIT - Answer

Ok, after some help I was able to find out why I was getting this issue. At the top of this file I had `namespace App\DB;` because of this Php was not able to find the `PDO` class. So, actually putting a `\` in front is actually the correct way to do it.

Big thanks to IMSoP, tete0148, Jim Wright.

Comment: Important question: when you actually run the code, can the class be found?

Comment: I will be honest and say that I have not been able to test that theory out yet, still have to build to register class etc etc

Comment: Aha, so rather than jumping to the conclusion that PHPStorm is at fault here, you need to learn about namespaces; PHPStorm is trying to save you time because *your code has an error in it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have jumped to the conclusion that PHPStorm is telling you the wrong thing, but actually you need to learn [how namespaces in PHP work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

- Adding a leading backslash to a class name is a way to reference its absolute namespace path.
- In this case, the PDO classes are in the root namespace, so they are just `\PDO` etc; if they were in a namespace called `Acme\Widgets`, you would write `\Acme\Widgets\PDO` as the fully-qualified class name.
- Fully qualifying the name like this is necessary if the file you are writing is itself declaring code in a particular namespace; that is, if it has the `namespace` keyword at the top of the file. In that case, the bare name `PDO` is assumed to be a class *in the same namespace you are writing code in*. If your file begins `namespace ZOulhadj\DB`, then `new PDO` will be expanded as though you'd written `new ZOulhadj\DB\PDO`.
- If this is the case, it is not just PHPStorm which will not be able to find the class - PHP itself will also fail to find the class. PHPStorm is pointing out an error to you so you can fix it before you run the code.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you clearing this up for me. The namespace that I am using is `namespace App\DB` and the class being DBConnect.

Comment: @ZOulhadj Bingo. So if you actually ran this code, you would get an error `Could not find class App\DB\PDO`, because that is what `new PDO` will mean in this particular file.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a backslash before class names because PHP standard classes are located in the root namespace.

```
\PDO
\PDOException
```

Or add a use statement at the top of your file.

```
use \PDO;
use \PDOException;
```

Note that PHPStorm can automatically import classes by pressing alt+enter while the cursor is over a warning.

Comment: This is the answer but he don't want to write proper syntax (it appears) so he might downvote you too ;-)

Comment: Nah I did not downvote but thank you for trying to help me :-)

Comment: If you just want the warning to disappear, you can either fix the problem as I mentioned or disable the inspection that causes this in project settings.

Answer (score 1):

@yann-chabot's (deleted) answer is correct that it will work if you add `\` before the classes but he is not clear on why.

In PHP backslashes are used to determine namespaces, and the PDO class is in the root namespace.

If you are in the same namespace as another class, you do not need to specify the namespace when using it. Otherwise, you should specify the namespace.

A simple way of thinking about namespaces are as folders.

For more info see the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

Comment: For me personally, I don't really mind if I need to use namespaces and whatnot but a few months ago I was learning PDO and I remember not having to use namespaces or anything like that which seems a little weird :/

Comment: The file you are editing is probably not in the root namespace, therefore PDO not being found.

Comment: @ZOulhadj It's not PDO that is requiring namespaces, it's *your code*. I am willing to bet that somewhere at the top of your file, you have the keyword `namespace`; that is you using namespaces.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes your answer help me understand this. Thank you.